Significance of coefficients in GARCH-MIDAS model
I used the GARCH-MIDAS model to check the relationship in stock volatility and epu, but the some countries’ $\alpha$ (the long term volatility parameter) is 0, and the p value is 1. The condition of this model $\alpha$ should more than 0. I don’t know why. And the same type data in other countries can get the normal significant results.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The condition of this model alpha should more than 0. Why? Could you elaborate on the model and on this condition? What is EPU?

thank you for your answer. I get this model in this paper < STOCK MARKET VOLATILITY AND MACROECONOMIC FUNDAMENTALS> by Robert F. Engle, Eric Ghysels, and Bumjean Sohn.(https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/43554794.pdf). EPU is economic policy uncertainty. I see the paper about GARCH-midas model, alpha > 0 maybe a precondition.

Thank you. Consider incorporating the additional information into the body of your post, as it is better visible there than in a comment. Is there a specific section of the paper that states $\alpha>0$ is a must?
